# ToolStripContainer equivalent of AutoScrollMinSize

Tags: .net, winforms, scroll

In Winforms (.NET 2.0+), **Form** has **AutoScrollMinSize** so you can set the minimum area that the scrollbars help you maintain. What's the equivalent in **ToolStripContainer.ContentPanel** (ie: **ToolStripContainer**)? All of the methods I can find (AutoScroll, AutoScrollMargin, AutoScrollMinSize, etc.) say "This property is not relevant for this class."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this area doesn't have these kinds of attributes. The closest you can come is to dock a container (eg: Panel) and use the container's **AutoScrollMinSize**.

Answer (score 1):

In Winforms vb.net 2008, you can use AutoScrollMinSize even though it doesn't come up in Intellisense. It is inherited from the ScrollableControl class.

```
ToolStripContainer1.TopToolStripPanel.AutoScrollMinSize = New Size(200, 200)
```